# Google Optimize anti-flicker snippet timed out

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-optimize

I cannot seem to resolve the warning message of the anti-flicker snippet from Google Optimize timing out.

The snippet is installed at the top of the `<head>` tag before the gtag optimize JS code.
I have tried changing the timeout value up to 6000, still not working.

```js
<style>.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} </style>
<script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
(a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
})(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',2000,
{'OPT_CONTAINER_ID':true});</script>
```

I'm still getting the following error message:

> The anti-flicker snippet might not have been configured correctly or
> the timeout value is too short. The anti-flicker timeout is a
> worst-case scenario. Your page will only be hidden for the full
> timeout if the experiment cannot execute sooner (and when it does, the
> page is unhidden immediately). When anti-flicker times out, your
> experiment doesn't run on that page load, which can limit the efficacy
> of your experiment and results. Regardless of timeout value, ensure
> that the Optimize plugin is deployed correctly and not late in the
> page (e.g. in the ).

Comment: Can you include the html you refer to in your question? Also, can you include the text of the error message you see in your question, rather than an image of it?

Comment: Updated @quicklikerabbit

Answer (score 2):

The snippets order is very important, first please check your `<head>` tag and become sure about the order:

1. Google anti-flicker
2. Google optimize
3. Google tag manager

Then open your browser developer tools and go to the **Elements** tab. Open the `<head>` tag and check if all the snippets are there (and in order) or not.

Also, please take a look at this article, which could be helpful:

[Tracking Optimize Anti-Flicker Snippet Timeout in Google Analytics](https://reflectivedata.com/tracking-optimize-anti-flicker-snippet-timeout-in-google-analytics/)

in addition, you can find out how to customize "anti-flicker snippet" from official Google documents:

[Customizing the anti-flicker snippet](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/antiflicker#changing_the_timeout)

Comment: I have the anti-flicker and Optimize running in the <head> for a good experience, but use a GDPR cookie plugin to control GTM. So there's no way to put that in the middle. What to do?

Comment: The order mentioned in the answer is not correct. The optimize tag should fire before the tag manager.  https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6315850